# Problem with Arduino and pySerial

Tags: python, c, arduino, pyserial

I got a problem. I recently bought an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) board. I tried to make something funny like controlling an input from my computer. I used Python with [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) and the program is the following:

```
arduino = serial.Serial(portaCOM, 9600, timeout = 1)
... in loop ->
arduino.write(value)


  def sliderUpdate(self, event):
        pos = self.slider.GetValue()
        arduino.write(pos)
        time.sleep(.1)
        print arduino.readline()

try:
    arduino = serial.Serial(portaCOM, 9600, timeout = 1)
except:
    print "Errore di connessione alla porta seriale"
```

The write value should send the value to my board though USB.
The program loaded on board is:

```
 const int ledPin = 11;
 byte brightness;

 void setup(){
     Serial.begin(9600);
     pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
 }

 void loop(){
     while(Serial.available()){
         brightness = Serial.read();
         Serial.print(brightness);
         analogWrite(ledPin, brightness); //LED doesn't refresh the brightness
         delay(10);
     }
 }
```

My LED is working properly. I tried with the Fade example provided by Arduino and it's working..

I checked if the program is sending properly the data. Yes, it is. It returns the same thing I sent before.

It should retrieve the value sent and set `analaogWriter(pin, VALUE)`, but something is wrong or not working.

How can I fix this problem?

**Solution**

The Arduino code

```
const int ledPin = 11;
byte valoreLed;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
    while(Serial.available()){
        valoreLed = Serial.read();
        analogWrite(ledPin, valoreLed);
        delay(20);
    }
}
```

Python script code:

```
pos = self.slider.GetValue()
arduino.write(chr(pos))
```

Thank you to everybody!! :)

Comment: can you elaborate what it _is_ doing ? does the led stay lit? does it stay off ?  What values are you sending from python ? can you add a read in python to make sure the value is being echoed back to you ?

Comment: Also can you post more of your python code, you probably don't have the com port correct

Comment: I'm trying to set the value of a led...
-Does the led stay lit? Well when i'm sending the first data the led is on and stays with the same value even if i change it..
-I'm sending from python an Int 
-print arduino.readline() it's funny..it's returning the same value I sent...but it's not setting properly the value in "analogWriter(pin, value)"

Comment: def update(self, event):
        pos = self.slider.GetValue()
        arduino.write(pos)
        time.sleep(.1)
        print arduino.readline()

try:
    arduino = serial.Serial(portCOM, 9600, timeout = 1)
except:
    print "Error"

Comment: What values are you sending via python ? try sending 0x10 and 0xAA or something, if you are sending ascii values (such as '1' '2' '3') you won't notice a change because in hex they are so close together in value, analogWrite()'s second argument is looking for a 0-255 value which is the extreme of 1 byte, you could use 'atoi()' on the arduino, but then you have to buffer more than 1 byte if you want a value greater than 9 (or 0x09)

Comment: Yes i'm trying to send a ascii value like 1-2-3...

Comment: i think the problem is really in the values because we send the value to arduino and arduino sends response with the same value correctly.. we put to pyserial com3 an int value..

Comment: @fran: sending ascii values like 1-2-3 will not show you any difference in led brightness, try multiplying the value by 28; add brightness = atoi(brightness) * 28;  after brightness = serial.read(); on the arduino.

Comment: Also try adding to your setup(){ .. } analogWrite(ledPin, 200); delay(500); analogWrite(ledPin, 0);  to make sure your led is functioning properly

Comment: the led it's working..if I send (char(0x10)) it's working..it's setting properly the led...

Comment: Have you checked the hypothesis in my second answer that the problem is with `arduino.readline()` waiting for a newline that never comes?

Comment: yes, sending a single char is working, I tried by the serial monitor sending a single random char and it's working..how to do this in python now? i mean handling the newline problem?

Comment: Does the `Serial` class you're using have a `read` method? Use that, or change your Arduino code to output a newline after every char.

Comment: I used Serial.read() in my python script plus Serial.print(valueLed) in arduino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, make sure your LED is properly connected. Anode (longer pin) to PWM 11 port and cathode (shorter pin) to ground, also you may need to add a resistor between cathode and ground depending on LED.
2. Make sure you're writing to the right port from python (that FTDI cable is associated with in your OS).
3. If you're not using FTDI cable with USB connector, make sure that all of the pins are connected to the right inputs.
4. What is the value of `value` in your example? Try `arduino.write(chr(0xFF))`, does LED stay lit?

Comment: all works, it is only a code problem.. for the 4).. when i send chr(0xFF) the led stay off

Comment: I've done an error.. with 0xFF stay on at the max.. reads the values in hexadecimal..

Comment: if I send (chr(0xff)) the led stays lit!! I tried with other hex values and it's staying lit..

Answer (score 1):

I see in your comments that the LED works with the first character, but you don't see a change with the different characters.  Definitely make sure you're sending ASCII characters that are significantly different from the previous characters, e.g. send an ASCII 0 followed by an ASCII 255.

Edit:
Since you say the FadeLED example works, can you just take that example and add serial port functionality to it?  For example, only fade after a serial character is received.  This will at least get you confident that the serial port and leds can coexist in code you write.  Also, I assume you're using the FadeLED example from [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Fade).  If so, make sure you've set the correct pin number, as the reference code uses pin 9, but your sample code uses pin 11.

Another Edit:
You say you receive the characters back properly from the Arduino, but you're using the pySerial `ReadLine` function, which should block until it sees a newline, and I don't see anything in the Arduino code that would generate a newline that wasn't sent to it first.  To eliminate the number of variables in the question, try using HyperTerminal or a similar COM port program to send bytes to the Arduino, rather than your Python program.  For example, you can send space characters (ASCII 32) and '}' characters (ASCII 125), which should be different enough to create a visible difference in the LED.

Comment: we tried with another simple program like fade in the examples ad led works perfectly.. in python we receive the response from arduino with the correct value that we have previously send.. but in this case analogwrite seems to not refresh

Comment: Ok if i send the data by the Serial Monitor the led is working properly..byt how can I fix this using python?

Comment: using arduino.read instead of arduino.readline i get strange values!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `arduino.readline()` waits for a newline, and you Arduino code never sends a newline. Hence the Python code blocks indefinitely after sending the first value.

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by establishing which side of the serial port harbours the problem.

First of all, can you drive the LED using a hard-coded loop on the Arduino. Does the LED change its brightness as expected?

Once that's out of the way, can you make the Arduino do something visibly correct when sending stuff manually from a terminal app (e.g. the one built into the Arduino IDE). This may require changes to the Arduino code.

Once that's working, I would then focus on the Python code, making sure you're talking to the right COM port etc.

Comment: in python we receive the response from arduino with the correct value that we have previously send.. but in this case analogwrite seems to not refresh

Comment: Well I tried before simply turning on a led.. then i tried the fade example provided by arduino...everything is working.. now i'm trying to pass the desired data by python and here i'm failing.

Comment: Can you successfully drive the Arduino from a terminal app?

Answer (score -1):

"the write value should send the value to my board through USB"

If this is not a typo, then you can not use PySerial to access USB ports.  There is pyUSB instead, and probably others.

Comment: the arduino uses a ftdi which will show up as a com port and is pyserial compatible